# MySQL Joins of tables with different columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a table that needs to be a combination of selected columns from three or more tables. I don't have any sample data, just added the columns for explanation.

Table 1

```
A|B1|C1|D1|E1|F1|G1|H1|I1|J1
```

Table 2

```
A|B2|C2|D2|E2|F2|G2
```

Table 3

```
A|B3|C3|D3|E3|F3|G3
```

Resultant New table must have

```
A|B1|E1|F1|G1|J1|C2|D2|G2|B3|D3|F3
```

I'm not sure if I need to use a FULL JOIN or use UNIONS. 
Each of these tables contain more than 400,000 rows. Any help here on what query needs to be included would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below query:

```
select t1.A,t1.B1,t3.E1,t1.F1,t1.G1,t1.J1,t2.C2,t2.D2,t2.G2,t3.B3,t3.D3,t3.F3 
from table1 t1  join table2 t2 on t1.A = t2.A
join table3 t3 join table2 t2 on t3.A = t2.A
```

As [Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157640/palec) commented correctly in the other answer, so adding a bit of explanation to the answer.

You need to use the JOINS for this problem instead of UNION. The reason why I am saying to use JOINS over UNION is UNION combines the data/result of two or more queries into a single result set which includes all the rows which exist in the queries in your UNION. But when you are using JOINs, you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on logical relationships between the tables.

Also to add that you should add an alias name to your table so that it becomes easy to retrieve the column in the select query and also while linking the table.

Comment: get an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't2.c2 in 'field list'. Is this because t2.c2 is not found in table1

Comment: @user3616977:- Yes if it is not present then the error is correct. But your table2 has the column C2(which you have shown) so in that case it should work. You just have to name the table which contains C2 column, if it is table1 then use t1.C2 and if it is table2 then use t2.C2. And if column C2 does not exist then delete that part from your query.

Comment: Got it...My query was screwed up...Thanks a lot for the response

Answer (score 0):

`Join` is the correct way:

```
select table1.A,B1,E1,F1,G1,J1,C2,D2,G2,B3,D3,F3 from table1 join table2 on table1.A = table2.A
join table3 join table2 on table3.A = table2.A
```

Comment: I get an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't2.c2 in 'field list'. Is this because t2.c2 is not found in table1

Comment: @user3616977 But not from my query.

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.